# Python end = "\r" does not work in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I've been trying to get my timer to count down from 25 minutes and applying it to a label with tkinter. However, every time it counts down, it will print the updated timer on a new line. It will look like
25:00
24:59
24:58
...
instead of updating the timer label. Here is my code

```
for i in range(4):
    timer = 1*60

    while timer:

        minutes = timer // 60
        seconds = timer % 60
        
        display = ('{:02d}:{:02d} '.format(minutes, seconds))
        
        print(display, end = "\r")

        time.sleep(1)
        timer -= 1

        label = tk.Label(frame, text = display, bg = "green")
        label.pack()
        root.update()`
```

Comment: Add `flush=True`

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  That can't be your exact code.  And I know it's not your exact code, because the timer here starts with 1:00 not 25:00

Comment: First, don't use while loop in main thread of tkinter application because it will block tkinter `mainloop()` from handling pending events and updates.  Second, better create `label` once and update its text in each iteration.  The "\r" works fine in my Windows 7 command terminal.

Comment: What environment are you running this code in?  IDLE's shell window, for example, doesn't support any control characters other than newline, so you simply cannot do overprinting.